# Outlook Sent Items missing for one user

Tags: outlook-2007

I'm use Exchange 2010, with Outlook 2007, but one users is having a problem where her 'Sent items' are showing as empty. However, these sent items are visible if the user login in via OWA.

I have tried the following, but with no success -

- Check that Outlook is not using Cached Exchange Mode (it's not)
- Turn off all Rules and Alerts (There are only two, and turning them
  off doesn't help)
- Log the user off and back on
- Open Outlook in Safe Mode (outlook.exe /safe - no joy)

Can anyone please suggest what I should try next? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Create another profile for the user and see what it looks like. I suspect that you have Cached Exchange Mode disabled but still have an OST. I've found multiple cases where offline use seems to be stuck "halfway" on / off.